# What kind of syntax is it to open the brackets after the VStack and describe body in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm newbie for Swift UI. Which syntax parts do I have to study for understanding below code?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("aaa")
            Text("bbb")
        }
    }
}
```

Below are what I want to understand

1. is body read-only property? So is VStack { ... } implicitly returned value?
2. VStack is struct, how brace can follow right after VStack? And how are Text Views able to be followed in brace? which syntax do I have to study to understand it?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) It's called a "trailing closure"

Comment: `VStack` is a structure and its initializer has a content parameter which expects a closure `content: () -> Content)`. As already mentioned in Swift when the last parameter is a closure you can use a "trailing closure" syntax and pass it after the initializer parentheses and if you are not passing any value inside you can omit them. `init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, content: () -> Content)`

Comment: `body` is an instance property with a getter and no setter. It is supposed to return `some View` a generic structure which its generic conforms to View protocol

Comment: View.body uses `@ViewBuilder` which is a type of ResultBuilder, refer https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID630.